# Deleting entire linked list in python

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

I code a program that creates a single linked list and now I am trying to delete the entire list.

First, I assign self.head to a variable, called current, but the function didn't work,and the program prints the entire list.

"""

```
def deleteLinkedList(self):
        
    current = self.head
    while current is not None:

        nextNode = current.next
        current = None
        current = nextNode
```

"""

Result:

[image]

But, when I change the code, the program print the list is empty.

New code:

"""

```
def deleteLinkedList(self):
          
    while self.head is not None:
        nextNode = self.head.next
        self.head = None
        self.head = nextNode
```

"""

Result:

[image]

I couldn't understand why the second code works and the first not. Why the nodes were not deleted when I use a variable instead of self.head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print memory address of current and self.head you will see that they are not the same because when you do current = None, current point to an another memory case (which contains the None value) but it doesn't affect your self.head variable. That's why your list is not empty with your first code.

```py
def delete(self):
        current = self.head
        print("current adress = " + hex(id(current)))
        print("self.head adress = " + hex(id(self.head)))
        while current is not None:
            nextNode = current.next
            current = None
            print("current adress = " + hex(id(current)))
            print("self.head adress = " + hex(id(self.head)))
            current = nextNode
```

output :

```
current adress = 0x7f9304ecdcd0  //print before while current = self.head so same address
self.head adress = 0x7f9304ecdcd0
current adress = 0x90a9f0     //current = None so current address change
self.head adress = 0x7f9304ecdcd0 //self.head doesn't change
current adress = 0x90a9f0
self.head adress = 0x7f9304ecdcd0
```